# how to install my app on myfan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I am developing an application for my fan page everything works fine but I can not install it onthe fan page only users.
it takes to install a fan page?

Answer (score 12):

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&display=popup&next=YOUR_URL

YOUR_URL should be the Page Tab URL from app settings.

Comment: YOUR_URL doesn't have to be the Page Tab URL, you can just use http://www.facebook.com if you like

Answer (score 9):

```
http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY&pages
```

Replace YOUR_API_KEY with your Application Key and then choose which FanPage do you want to install it to.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://developers.facebook.com

Select the App you wish to use

on the Settings tab scroll down and click + Add Platform, there you can select "Page Tab" after which you will be given a config screen

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)

Comment: this is necessary before using http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY&pages

Answer (score -1):

Get your app id
then go to
    http://facebook.com/APP_ID

that will show your APP profile page.

On the left side you need to click on

> Add to my Page

you will see all the facebook pages you own, just need to select the one you want

[image: Left side bar of APP profile page]